# Initializing code using pageInit() in jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, this, page-init

I am attempting to initialize javascript for a jQuery mobile page using the pageInit() function. I have outlined some attempts below that I can't seem to get working. Can any one tell me what I'm doing wrong. Also is there a way to do this using $(this) instead of using the pages explicit name?

pageInit.html:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.css"
    />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.20/jquery-ui.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="functions.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        alert("script");
        $(this).live('pageinit', function (event) {
            //$('pageInit.html').live( 'pageinit',function(event){
            //$('#pageInit').live( 'pageinit',function(event){
            //$('#pageInit.html').live( 'pageinit',function(event){
            alert("Page Initialized");
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pageinit` event is fired on the document. It doesn't make sense to use `live`, either. Instead I would use `bind`. For example:

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function (event) {
        alert("Page Initialized");
    });
```

Take a look at the [jQuery mobile documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html) for more information.